# MeteorJs aldeed-autoform, How to get desired value from boolean checkbox

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

There is boolean checkbox in my code. what my perception is that on-check, it should return its value as true and upon unchecked, it should return its value as false. But I am facing different situation, which is as follows:

On page's initial load, it shows message: 'not selected' 
When I make the checkbox checked, it shows me value : 'true'
When I uncheck the checkbox, it stick to show me value : 'true'
So it always shows me value 'true', even how many times I make it checked or unchecked.

Can someone guide me what is the problem and how it can be rectified to get desired results:

Here is autoform HTML code :

```
{{#autoForm  collection='Collections.Category' validation='submit' id='CategoryInsertForm' class="form-horizontal  form-with-legend"  role="form" type='method' meteormethod='CategoryInsertMethod' }}

{{ currentFieldValue 'isParent' }}

{{> afFormGroup  name='isParent' id='isParent' type="boolean-checkbox"}}

{{#if afFieldValueIs name="isParent" value= 'true'}}
{{> afFieldInput name='parentId' id='parentId' class='form-control'}}
{{/if}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Here is JS code:

```
Template.registerHelper("currentFieldValue", function (fieldName) {
    return AutoForm.getFieldValue( fieldName) || "not selected";
});
```

Here is Schema code:

```
Collections.Category =  new Mongo.Collection('category');

Schemas.Category = new SimpleSchema({

    catId:{
         type: String,
         optional: true,
         unique: true
    },
    isParent: {
        type: Boolean,
        optional: true,
        defaultValue: false,
      // ,allowedValues: [true, false]
        label: "Parent category"

    },
    parentId: {
        type: String,
        label: "ParentID",
        optional: true

    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        optional:true
    }

});

Collections.Category.attachSchema(Schemas.Category);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by creating a helper like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
'change .myCheckboxClass': function(event) {
    clickedElement = event.target;
    clickedElement.value = !clickedElement.checked;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using the following setup for a similar problem:

Template:

```
<template name='test'>
 {{autoFormTest}}
 {{> quickForm collection="Sample" id="sampleForm" type="update" doc=this}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.test.helpers({ 
    autoFormTest: function(){
        return AutoForm.getFieldValue("radiobuttonField", "sampleForm").toString();
    }
})
```

Relevant part of schema:

```
radiobuttonField: {
    optional: true,
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Is it true?",
    autoform: {
        type: "boolean-radios",
        trueLabel: "Yes",
        falseLabel: "No "
    }
}
```

The helper will return either a `false` or `true` string, but it defaults to `false`. So there are two important parts related to your question:

1. you should specify the name of the form in your helper `AutoForm.getFieldValue(..., "sampleForm")`
2. if you want to get back string value (which can be written out) out of a boolean selector you should convert it into string `AutoForm.getFieldValue(...).toString()`

Hope that helps.